# Assign user role by text field in Wordpress (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, actions, user-roles, user-registration

I have a virtual store with woocommerce where I use the USER REGISTRATION plugin to register new customers. This plugin allows the creation of custom fields.
I created a custom text field called "STATE REGISTRATION". In this field the user can write something or leave it blank.

My demand is that when creating a new user, wordpress will read this "STATE REGISTRATION" field and see if there is any content filled in it.

If you have something filled out, I need the user to have a second "ROLE" added to their profile.

I created this role before and it's called "IE".

I'm try this, but doesnt works!

```
add_action( 'user_registration_after_register_user_action', 'adiciona_role_ie', 9999, 3 );
function adiciona_role_ie( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {
    $billing_ie = '';
    if ( isset( $valid_form_data['billing_ie'] ) && ! empty( $valid_form_data['billing_ie']->value ) ) {
        echo $billing_ie = $valid_form_data['billing_ie']->value;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $billing_ie ) ) {
    
    add_filter('user_registration_after_register_user_action', 'wc_assign_custom_role', 10, 1);

    function wc_assign_custom_role($args) {
      $args['role'] = 'ie';
      
      return $args;
    }
        //update_user_meta( $user_id, 'ie', $role );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Lucas, welcome to WPSE. In order to get a faster response, I suggest you add a little bit [more of context, and information to your question and explain what you already tried](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), a wee a little bit about your knowledge and skill with WordPress.

Comment: Hi, try to read again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
function ur_update_role( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {
global $table_prefix;
$assign_roles_list = array();
if( isset( $valid_form_data['billing_ie']) && !empty( $valid_form_data['billing_ie']->value ) ) {
array_push( $assign_roles_list, 'ie' );
}
if ( ! empty( $assign_roles_list ) ) {
// Re-ordering roles according to priority.
$user_roles_list = ur_get_default_admin_roles();
foreach ( $user_roles_list as $key => $value ) {
if ( ! in_array( $key, $assign_roles_list, true ) ) {
unset( $user_roles_list[ $key ] );
} else {
$user_roles_list[ $key ] = true;
}
}
$field_name = $table_prefix . 'capabilities';
update_user_meta( $user_id, $field_name, $user_roles_list );
}
}
```