# Add another user role based on a defined input field in Wordpress (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles

for a WooCommerce shop, the roles customer and corporate_customer are primarily used.
As soon as a customer registers and enters a tax number in their billing address in the optional field (ID: _billing_eu_vat_number), we want to add the corporate_customer role to their existing role (customer).
Automatically adding the corporate_customer role and sending us an e-mail would be ideal.
During my search I came across this post: [Assign user role by text field in Wordpress (Woocommerce)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/380987/assign-user-role-by-text-field-in-wordpress-woocommerce)
Unfortunately we could not successfully adapt the code for ourselves. What have I done wrong?

```php
function ur_update_role( $valid_form_data, $form_id, $user_id ) {
    global $table_prefix;

    $assign_roles_list = array();

    if ( isset( $valid_form_data['billing_eu_vat_number']) && ! empty( $valid_form_data['billing_eu_vat_number']->value ) ) {
        array_push( $assign_roles_list, 'corporate_customer' );
    }

    if ( ! empty( $assign_roles_list ) ) {
        // Re-ordering roles according to priority.
        $user_roles_list = ur_get_default_admin_roles();

        foreach ( $user_roles_list as $key => $value ) {
            if ( ! in_array( $key, $assign_roles_list, true ) ) {
                unset( $user_roles_list[ $key ] );
            } else {
                $user_roles_list[ $key ] = true;
            }
        }

        $field_name = $table_prefix . 'capabilities';

        update_user_meta( $user_id, $field_name, $user_roles_list );
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem here?

Thanks very much!
Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code snippet to your WordPress theme's functions.php file.

Define the new user role and capabilities (you can customize this based on your needs)

```
function add_custom_roles() {
    add_role( 'corporate_customer', 'Corporate Customer', array(
        'read' => true,
        'edit_posts' => true,
        'delete_posts' => false,
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_roles' );
```

A function to update the user role based on the custom field value

```
function custom_user_role_based_on_tax_number( $user_id ) {
    // Get the user's billing tax number from the user meta
    $billing_tax_number = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_eu_vat_number', true );
    // Check if the user has entered a tax number
    if ( ! empty( $billing_tax_number ) ) {
        // Add the custom user role 'corporate_customer'
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $user->add_role( 'corporate_customer' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'custom_user_role_based_on_tax_number' );
```

When a customer registers and enters a tax number in their billing address during the WooCommerce checkout process, they will be assigned the custom user role 'corporate_customer'.

Please note that this code assumes that you have a custom user meta field with the meta key 'billing_eu_vat_number' in the user's profile. If you don't have this field, you will need to add as user meta.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hello Vishal,
many thanks for your response.
Since the corporate_customer role already exists, I think the first block of code isn't necessary.
I've tried every constellation, but it doesn't work. I entered the code variants as a code snippet...
I also changed billing_eu_vat_number to _billing_eu_vat_number with no success.
Any idea how to solve it?
We would like a registered user to get an additional role as soon as they enter a UID number in their billing address, i.e. before checkout
Thanks